# tilde_expand: No such user .ssh

Tags: alias

I have this weirdest error where a single IP address with `ssh` would immediately return an error

```
arthur@arthur-laptop:~$ ssh 192.168.1.85
tilde_expand: No such user .ssh
```

I feel like it's an issue with autocompletion or something similar. And I have no idea where to look to fix this.

A few info points :

- The error does not show up when running the command as root
- The error does not show up when using any other IP address (it only fails for 192.168.1.85)
- `which ssh` returns `/usr/bin/ssh`
- There is no weird aliases in `.bash_aliases`, nor in `.bash_profile` nor in `bash_logout`

I'm clueless. This is obviously a weird alias set up somewhere, but I have no idea where to look. Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `tilde_expand: No such user .ssh` sounds like `ssh` is trying to expand `~.ssh`, rather than presumably `~/.ssh`.

I would check `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (or alternative ssh configuration files) for typos of paths.

Comment: Spot on. I had no idea I had a `.ssh/config` file laying around, probably a bad copy/paste. Indeed it contained something like `IdentityFile ~.ssh/id_rsa_server`.

Comment: @ArthurAttout this kind of error *always* means you forgot a `/`  somewhere.  The trick is in finding it...